# How to avoid "Operation not permitted" on macOS when `sudo` and `bypass` don't do the trick

Tags: macos, file-io, sudo

On macOS (High Sierra) when I attempt to list the file at the path

```
/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store
```

I get the error "`Operation not permitted`". Using `sudo` doesn't better it and even employing the `bypass` helper doesn't change anything:

```
sudo /System/Library/Extensions/TMSafetyNet.kext/Contents/Helpers/bypass ls -l /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store
```

gives "`Operation not permitted`" as well. How can I list/access the file under the path `/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store`?

**Additional info:**

An list of the the enclosing directory via `ls -al /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles` displays:

```
drwxr-xr-x   5 root  wheel   160 13 Apr  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x  85 root  wheel  2720 28 Sep 06:27 ..
drwxr-xr-x@  4 root  wheel   128 16 Dec  2017 Settings
drwx------   3 root  wheel    96  1 Oct 21:56 Setup
ls: Store: Operation not permitted
```

Consistently, but rather  strangely `Store` cannot be listed. This happens both when executing `ls` as current user and via `sudo`.

Comment: Could you give us the `ls -la` of `/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles`?

Comment: @tukan See my question. I have added the relevant details.

Comment: did you try `sudo ls -la` too?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned in the question it happens both as current user and via sudo.

Comment: Do you have system integrity on (`csrutil status`)? -> this is the most probable reason you will have to disable the protection to see the file.  Did you *verified* your disk?

Comment: @tukan SIP is **enabled**. Haven't verified disk yet. Will do that next.

Comment: You need to disable SIP in order to view `.../Store`

Comment: I guess the question is: what are you trying to do? There is likely another way of interrogating the system for that info.

Comment: @tukan Why on earth do I have to disable SIP when I just want to *view* a directory? I do not change anything! - I thought SIP is about modifications to some areas of the filesystem...

Comment: @benwiggy I just compare the start up disk to a backup - and of course I *can* exclude  `Store` but I want to understand why...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most probable reason is the [*system integrity protection (SIP)*](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Security/Conceptual/System_Integrity_Protection_Guide/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection/ConfiguringSystemIntegrityProtection.html) - `csrutil` is the command line utility.  You need to disable it to view the directory.

- To view your status you need to:

`csrutil status`

- To disable it (which is usually a **bad** idea):

`csrutil disable` (then you will probably need to reboot).

- To enable it (which should be turned back on when you are done):

`csrutil enable`

Comment: I can confirm that **disabling SIP** solves the access issue: Then `sudo ls -al /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store` lists the content of that directory. - This is not the solution I was hoping for, but it is a solution (and probably the only possible one).

Comment: @halloleo well that is how the MacOS works.  If SIP it is covered by SIP the "ordinary" user does not have an access, to guard the system from the ordinary users.

Comment: **Disabling SIP** is using a bulldozer to open a door.  **Full Disk Access** is the key, as explained above.

Answer (score 18):

TWO things you can try below...

Sometimes "operation not permitted" relates to permissions, so one thing you can try to solve the problem is to go into the permissions for the folder in question.

1. Open Finder, and get to the folder which is giving you the failed operations (such as "ls").
2. Right-click the folder, and select "Get Info"
3. Add users to have read/write permission for the folder; aka, add your user profile (you).

Another thing which could be causing the problem...
It could be that Terminal app itself isn't able to access the data via privacy fireballing.  To solve that:

1. Click on Apple symbol top left and select "System Preferences"
2. Open "Security & Privacy"
3. Select the "Privacy" menu
4. On the left-hand side, select "Full Disk Access"
5. on lower left, click the lock and enter your MacOS password or swipe your finger (eyes).
6. Click the plus button on the right to add Terminal app to the list of things with Full Disk Access.  Make sure Terminal is checked when you're done.
7. reset the lock, and you're done.
8. shut down Termainal, then restart it.

This should allow Terminal access to the folder in question.

for more info:  https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/

Comment: As mentioned by the OP, turning off SIP is not really a useful solution.  I was thrown off by the first part of this answer (changing file permission is an obvious thing to try).  But the second part of this answer is, IMHO, THE correct answer.  Under "Privacy" there is also a "Files and Folders" item.  In my case, the offending directory, Documents, was not checked.  I checked it, and voilà, I can access the Documents folder from the iTerm app.  So I think this answer is the best answer.

Comment: **Operation not permitted** never relates to permissions - ignore the misleading first part which can only fix **Permission Denied** errors.