# iOS 17.0 Simulator - Failed - Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator falied

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode15

After downloading the Xcode beta and attempting to install the iOS 17.0 Simulator, an error message popped up saying, "Failed - Registering simulator runtime with CoreSimulator failed."

I have come across other solutions to this issue, but being new to this field, I was unable to resolve it on my own.

I have more than 18GB of free storage and have tried deleting and re-downloading Xcode-beta multiple times.

If anyone is able to assist me with this problem, I would greatly appreciate it!

[image]

Comment: Make more space on your disk, restart your computer and try again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @EmilioPelaez! However, I have now more than 25GB and it didn't work.

Comment: Answered here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/77133957/3507433

Comment: I was having problem with iOS 17.0 (21A328)
How I solved it explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/77251040/12731334

Answer (score 24):

I was also encountering this problem, and here is the solution that worked for me:

***Note: Ensure that you have enough space available on your hard disk.***

### Solution

**1-** Go to the URL: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

**2-** You will be need to login with your developer account.

**3-** Download "iOS 17 Simulator Runtime".

[image]

**4-** Download may paused but be patient. Eventually after a long time it will downloaded (Use IDM or Chrome if you have.These software have better tendency to resume downloads).

**5-** once the file downloaded open terminal and run the commands:

```
xcrun simctl runtime add "Path to downloaded dmg file"
```

For example. `xcrun simctl runtime add "Downloads/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"`

6-  Run
`xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS`

Note: Make sure you have enabled full access option for terminal in your mac don't know how?check here: [How to avoid "Operation not permitted" on macOS when `sudo` and `bypass` don't do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100326/how-to-avoid-operation-not-permitted-on-macos-when-sudo-and-bypass-dont-d)

Comment: I Installed it but I can't Create a Simulator, It just not working

Comment: It's not working for me showing me an error related to permission.

Terminal exception:
Operation not permitted
Accessing '~/Downloads/iOS_17.2_beta_Simulator_Runtime.dmg' requires Security & Privacy approval.

Comment: Click on Apple symbol top left and select "System Preferences"
Open "Security & Privacy"
Select the "Privacy" menu
On the left-hand side, select "Full Disk Access"
on lower left, click the lock and enter your MacOS password or swipe your finger (eyes).
Click the plus button on the right to add Terminal app to the list of things with Full Disk Access. Make sure Terminal is checked when you're done.
reset the lock, and you're done.
shut down Termainal, then restart it.

Comment: "It shows no such file or directory", even though I checked out the correct path and spellings

Comment: @Mashood.H you missed the last step:

6- To download and install Simulator runtimes `xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS`

This will enable you to create iOS Simulators

Comment: yes thank you @IsaacPitwa. I'll add that too.

Comment: @Mashood.H Yeah this is a good answer. It works for me. And also must have free space more than 30GB in my case.

also This Could be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

It's caused by not enough free space on your disk (see [this thread](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/732407)). I had 60 GB free and was still hitting the problem. But this worked for me:

- delete old simulators from Xcode by going to Product > Destination > Manage  Run Destinations... then click the simulators tab, and right-click then delete for each simulator you no longer need.
- restart your mac (important!)

Then you should be able to install iOS 17 simulators.

Comment: this fixed the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue trying to setup my React Native environment for iOS, after a little reading i came across an article that described the problem as

> Error typically occurs when there is an issue with registering the
> simulator runtime with CoreSimulator. It can be triggered during the
> download and installation of simulator runtimes, such as the VisionOS
> Simulator, in Xcode 15.

And the possible causes being:

1. Insufficient Storage
2. Software Glitch (temporary issues with CoreSimulator or related services can trigger this error)
3. Network Problems (issues during the download process can also cause this error.)

In my case i had less storage, **cleared my storage to make space** and error still persisted, next i noticed there was a **pending MacOS update**, ran the update, restarted my mac and everything was fixed. Updates are mostly important for bug fixes.

For further reading on the article referenced above, access it [here](https://developermemos.com/posts/troubleshooting-registering-simulator-runtime-error-xcode-15).[image]

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. But after I made some free space on the hard drive - problem was fixed