# Could not download and install iOS 17.0 Simulator runtime with Xcode 15.0

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I'm getting an issue when attempting to install the **iOS 17.0 simulator** in **Xcode 15.0**. The problem is when Xcode updated to version 15, and now all the simulators I had previously downloaded have disappeared. Even though I have installed iOS 15.0 before, it doesn't seem to appear for me to run, and I'm getting an error message stating that I need iOS 17. Then when I try to download this from the xcode. I ended up with this error message.

[image]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

**Option 1:**
You can check the available free disk space on your MacBook. This usually becomes an issue when you have low space, and technically, you only need around 23GB of free disk space. However, I had to free up to 50GB to install it. You can manage your space and try to download it again.

**Option 2:**
You can try downloading and installing iOS 17.0 Simulator runtimes for a specific platform using the `Terminal`. Use the `-downloadPlatform` option and specify the platform like this:

```
xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS
```

**Option 3:**
You can download the iOS 17.0 simulator runtime from this link - https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

If your download speed is slow, you may need to use a VPN.

After downloading the runtime, follow the commands below in your Terminal:

```
sudo xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app
xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch
xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"
```

[image]

Find more information about installing additional simulator runtimes on the official Apple documentation - https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/installing-additional-simulator-runtimes

Comment: I redownloaded and had the same problem. My solution is so cliche. 
Just restart your Mac and reopen Xcode

Comment: options 3 working perfectly for me

Comment: For me all options did not work (despite 130 GB of free space). Then I noticed that I had **XCode 15.0.1** installed. So I downloaded **XCode 15** [here](https://developer.apple.com/download/all/?q=xcode) (not 15.0.1 or anything else). In addition I installed the corresponding command line tools, but not  sure if its necessary. Then I proceeded with your **option 3** and now it works again!

Comment: **Option 3** worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Option 3 worked for Mac M1. Thanks

Comment: `iOS 17.2 Simulator runtimes` still got this error and need to use option 3 to install

Comment: I downloaded **iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg** and option 3 worked for me.

Comment: Does 'iOS 17.2 simulator runtime' and 'iOS 17.2 SDK' mean the same thing?

Comment: Deeply Appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

For me the issue was solved by restarting my Mac (M1 Sonoma 14.0, if it helps to know this), reopened Xcode, and done. Building successfully again

Comment: this help me !! lol so funny

Comment: worked for me, thanks!

Comment: Occam's razor - worked for me

Comment: Likewise.  When all else fails... switch it off and switch it on again does the job.

Answer (score 11):

I was also facing this issue.Here is the solution worked for me:

**1-** Go to the URL: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

**2-** You will be need to login with your developer account.

**3-** Download "iOS 17 Simulator Runtime".

[image]

**4-** Download may paused but be patient. Eventually after a long time it will downloaded (Use IDM or Chrome if you have.These software have better tendency to resume downloads).

**5-** once the file downloaded open terminal and run the commands:

```
xcrun simctl runtime add "Path to downloaded dmg file"
```

For example. `xcrun simctl runtime add "~Downloads/iOS_17_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"`

```
 xcodebuild -downloadPlatform iOS
```

Note: Make sure you have enabled full access option for terminal in your mac don't know how?check here: [How to avoid "Operation not permitted" on macOS when `sudo` and `bypass` don't do the trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58100326/how-to-avoid-operation-not-permitted-on-macos-when-sudo-and-bypass-dont-d)

Answer (score 4):

I have been facing this problem twice. The only solution that helped me was to manually delete the current iOS 17.0 simulator and download + reinstall it.

Comment: Could you specify the details / steps you followed for that?

Answer (score 3):

All downloaded runtimes should be mounted before usage in Xcode. Unmounting them via Finder or DiskUtility makes Xcode to fail, and restaring Xcode is not enough. Redownloading images can help, but restarting your mac makes runtimes available again.

This command should do the same with already downloaded runtime without restarting:

```
sudo xcrun simctl runtime add /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/15ACE7E8-AFE4-4D64-8597-6D6913A32124.dmg
```

but without sudo it fails with error (because the owner of the file is system):

```
The operation couldn’t be completed. No such file or directory
```

and with sudo it fails with another error:

```
Unusable - Other Failure: Error Domain=SimDiskImageErrorDomain Code=5 "Duplicate of 15ACE7E8-AFE4-4D64-8597-6D6913A32124"
```

Exporting installed images in not working too because of "you don't have permissions to access Downloads" error, but the real cause is because the owner of dmg file is system. Xcode 15 is broken a little, isn't it?

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3):

The root cause is low disk space (50 GB is considered low).
Make sure to free up disk space and try the 3rd suggested option

Comment: I've got 66GB left of storage and it is considered low. But the download is only 7GB? Wtf Apple? Let me decide if that's "low".

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps someone, I was prompted to download 'ios 17.0' and it downloaded 'ios simulator 17.0.1' but kept complaining about wanting 'ios 17.0'
Clicking the download button on the platforms tab would do nothing.
In the end I deleted the 'ios simulator entry' and then agreed to download 'ios 17.0' again and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, I was having Xcode 15.0.1 and faced problem to run on iOS 17.2 simulator. Though it shows in the available Platforms it was not working.

I then installed Xcode 15.1 and then downloaded the iOS 17.2 simulator to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I my case was getting below error -

Failed to copy file /Users/dineshkkumar/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/com.apple.dmg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK17_2-17.2.0.0.dmg to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/Inbox/6DB4BFED-4649-464E-9D9F-107B47F0C06F.dmg.copying
Domain: SimDiskImageErrorDomain
Code: 6
User Info: {
DVTErrorCreationDateKey = "2023-12-31 15:57:42 +0000";
unusableErrorDetail = "Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Failed to copy file /Users/dineshkkumar/Library/Caches/com.apple.dt.Xcode/Downloads/com.apple.dmg.iPhoneSimulatorSDK17_2-17.2.0.0.dmg to /Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Images/Inbox/6DB4BFED-4649-464E-9D9F-107B47F0C06F.dmg.copying}";
}

Cause of issue -
Images and Inbox folder was missing causing - path not found

Resolved -
by creating missing folders - Images and Inbox under CoreSimulator folder

/Users/dineshkkumar/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/**Images/Inbox**

then run below command -

- xcode-select -s /Applications/Xcode.app

  xcodebuild -runFirstLaunch

  xcrun simctl runtime add "~/Downloads/iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg"

note - downloaded iOS_17.2_Simulator_Runtime.dmg from Apple developer portal

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error too. You need to free up storage space, try again later.

Answer (score -1):

Update to latest version of **xcode**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).