# Cannot download iSO17 in Xcode 15.0

Tags: build, download, xcode15, ios17

I am new to Xcode, when I am building an Ionic - Angular  app form Visual Studio Code in Xcode ver 15.0,  I get a prompt in Xcode :

> app > iOS 17.0 Not Installed --BUTTON {GET}--

However when I click GET , a recent download of the iOS17 simulator pops into view, and the download of iOS17 does not commence.

Possibly missing something very simple here but I can't seem to find a means to download iOS 17 and thus build the app.
Thnaks

Comment: Maybe the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77218811/could-not-download-and-install-ios-17-0-simulator-runtime-with-xcode-15-0 ?